# Why Counting Months (first, second) is not a Mitzvah from Torah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, names, calendar, months

**This is not a duplicate, the other question asks about adopting the Babylonian calendar system, please remove the notice.**

The original names for Hebrew months, as they appear in Torah - are just serial numbers, counting from Nissan, being the first month, Iyar the second etc. As in:

> "ויסעו מרעמסס בחודש הראשון, בחמישה עשר יום **לחודש הראשון**" (Num 33,3)
>
> "בשנת הארבעים, לצאת בני-ישראל מארץ מצריים, **בחודש החמישי**, באחד לחודש" (ibid 28)

Many interpreters mention that this is one of the ways of a remembering the Exodus.

This is consistent with the ruling of the Gemmorah that **"ישראל מונים ללבנה"**, which literally means "Israel **count** months". However, the current names we use were brought from the Babylon exile, and those names are proper names, **lacking the serial counting, and, therefore, remembering Nissan and the Exodus**.

How come such a big Deoraisoh issue was forgotten, and the Sages decided to override the naming of the Torah and the remembrance of the Exodus in counting Hebrew months?

Comment: Where do you get that it’s a commandment to count from Nissan? Further, why is it a problem that I call the months by a different name? Ask that we call the first day of the week Sunday instead of יום ראשון.

Comment: @DonielF " Ask that we call the first day of the week Sunday instead of יום ראשון" - IIRC, Ramba"m alludes to this idea and might have stated that there could be a halachic problem using these secular names. Can't say if it was Ramba"m or someone else. It's not a great analogy, here. After all, Esther and Daniel, as an example, use the Babylonian names for the months, so it is in Tanac"h. We certainly don't see this with the secular names of the week.

Comment: I think *Sefer Hatoda'ah* has a detailed explanation of why the Babylonian names were used. I think there was supposed to be a continual remembrance of our Galut, and it is supposed to help us pray for Redemption. However, I'm uncertain as to where you arrive at the notion that the usage of month names is in any form a way of overriding the remembrance of the Exodus. The Torah, nowhere, has a commandment regarding even how many months there are supposed to be in the year. Read esp. Ibn Ezra's long explanation on this problem. It may offer some couter-arguments to your premise.

Comment: Maybe you could distinguish your question better and get clearer answers if you first asked *if* there is an explicit commandment to count months, and if so, why the sages overrode it

Comment: Maybe instead of just *saying* that this isn’t a dupe, you can explain *why* it isn’t, what it is about your question that that one doesn’t address?

Comment: because it does not discuss counting the months and remembering Nissan as the first month of Exodus.

Comment: How did you get from "this is one of the ways of a remembering the Exodus" to "such a big Deoraisoh issue"?

Comment: @AlBerko (Remember to ping me when you’re responding - I won’t necessarily see your comments otherwise.) Your main question seems to be (final paragraph): “How come such a big Deoraisoh issue was forgotten, and the Sages decides to override the naming of the Torah and the remembrance of the Exodus in counting Hebrew months?” What’s the difference between that and “Why does our calendar follow the Babylonians’?” You include additional motivation, yes, but the essential question is the same.

Comment: @DonielF  I reread that question, I now understand it better. The OP asks about adopting the Bab. *calendar*, not names, though most responders referred to Bab. names only. Some of the answers might fit my question (although I'm not satisfied with them), but the question is totally different. We either need to change that question (addressing only the names) or clarify it as wrongly assuming that the whole calendar [system] was adopted. What do you think?

Comment: @AlBerko I still don’t see a difference. What is it that that question doesn’t address that yours does?